# Laravel GET parameters that include dots cannot be checked

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to determine whether a parameter is in the URL or not. I use:

`$request->has('key');`

And it's been working properly until now when I have to check wethere I have `openid.ns` parameter in the URL. If I remove the `.`(dot) everything works as expected, but:

> URL: myhost.dev/auth/login?openid.ns=http://google.bg/

And then

`dd($request->has('openid.ns');`

returns **false**.

If it's something like this:

> URL: myhost.dev/auth/login?openidns=http://google.bg/

And then

`dd($request->has('openidns');`

returns **true**.

What causes this odd behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if the `openid.ns` value is present on the request, you can do it by:

```
$request->has('openid_ns')
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working on laravel v5.4.15 doing unit tests. I examined the code and found that when it checks, the array is still ['some.key' => 'value'], and it's checking for a key 'some_key'. Is 'some.key' supposed to be translated to 'some_key' for storage in $request somewhere in middleware?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `.` notation is used while accessing arrays, [as documented](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests):

> When working on forms with array inputs, you may use "dot" notation to
>   access the arrays:
>
> $input = $request->input('products.0.name');